# Dynamic Form ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm searching for 2 days, how to create a dynamic form using ASP.NET and Visual Basic. I'm going to explain my problem:

- I have 3 different forms because on each form there are 3 radio
  buttons.
- I also have a main form that is loaded when I launch my program.
- When I click on the first radio button, the 1st Form is loaded.
- When I click on the second radio button, the 2nd Form is loaded.
- And also the same thing with the third radio button (Form 3 is loaded)

My question is : **Is it possible to create a Dynamic Form where all the 3 forms are integrated ?** I mean, if I click on radio button 1, the fields corresponding to this button are loaded. If I click on radio button 2, the fields corresponding to radio button 2 appears and the other fields corresponding to radio button 1 disappear.

If you have some solutions or some links would be great.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Look at Form controls and placing them into a webform page.

Comment: Sounds like you do know which Controls you want in each case of a radiobutton being selected. If so, use a MultiView or Panels and just switch between them depending on selection. Some code is Always the best way to get help around here though.

Comment: Thank for your answers. Actually I have no code to show :/
So I just wanted to know if it is possible to do.

Comment: Depending on your actual scenario maybe a [Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) control might fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a series of `<asp:Panel>` elements. These will render as HTML `<div>` elements. They all have a Visible property. Each one should contain the different sets of form elements that you want to be visible. In your code behind you can set the panels' Visible property True or False depending on which radiobutton was chosen by the user. In that way you can have one form, but where different parts of the form are displayed in different circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use a database ? (I'm using one actually)

Comment: It's very easy to do use a database with ASP.NET. What precisely do you want to use the database for?

Comment: It's a kind of a register form. The database is used to store the data inside it until the form has been sent to an email address. I actually use a database for the three different forms. My question was if it will work if I merge them ?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't see for certain but as long as you understand which values are which I can't think of an obvious reason why it can't. When the user submits the form, you just need to pick the values from your code-behind and store them in the database appropriately. If you need more detailed help, it's probably best to ask a separate question. If my answer helped you with the specific question you originally asked, please mark it as the accepted answer - thanks.